# CSS background color not showing up in nested <DIV>

Tags: css, html, background

I can not get my yellow background color to show up with the nested divs that show up in 3 separate columns. What am I doing wrong?

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div class="rightside">
   Test
   </div>
   <div class="rightside">
   Test
   </div>    
   <div class="rightside">
   Test
   </div>    
</div>
```

CSS below:

```
#wrapper {

  background-color: yellow;

}

div.rightside {

  width: 31%;
  margin: 0 1.33333em 0 0;
  display:inline;
  float:left;   

}
```

Here is my jsfiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/yPX5Q/2/

Thanks
Cheers

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to your wrapper div

```
#wrapper {
    background-color: yellow;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/yPX5Q/4/)**

Floating the inner divs essentially gives the wrapper div no height. By adding the overflow:auto it brings back the expected behavior.

Answer (score 0):

you can set `overflow:hidden;` http://jsfiddle.net/yPX5Q/3/ on the parent container or use a clearfix method with a pseudo element or extra element.

More info about floatting elements here : http://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/